# If and Else Condition in Ract js Render - Syntax Error

Tags: reactjs

i am new to REACT.js and your advise would be much appreciated

- i have a list of categories i have placed a post under
- i would like to display the categories based on a condition
- i am unsure why i am getting a syntax error - looked through it over and over

[image]

**i tried the below:**

```
<span className="categories">
  {
    if (post.author.name == "wastson") {
      Object.values(post.categories).map((category) => {
        return(
          <span>{category.name}</span>
        );
      })
    } else {
      return null;
    } 
  }
</span>
```

**but i get the error:
Failed to compile**
[image]

**BELOW ARE MY FILES**

app/scr/components/Blog/Index.js

```
import Layout from '../../components/Layout/Layout';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
    
class Index extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <Layout>
        <ul>
          {this.props.posts.map((post) => {
            if (post) {
              return(
                <li key={post.ID} className="card">
                  <div>{post.title}</div>
                  <div>{post.date}</div>
                  <span className="categories">
                    {
                      if (post.author.name == "wastson") {
                        Object.values(post.categories).slice(0, 1).map((category) => {
                          return(
                            <span>{category.name}</span>
                          );
                        })
                      } else {
                        return null;
                      } 
                    }
                  </span>
                </li>
              );
            } else {
              return null;
            }
          })}
        </ul>
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}

export default Index;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line javascript in JSX (the code within {}), does not support complex code like `if-else`, `for loops`, it is supposed to be one line code. The workaround for this is to use the ternary operator (`? :`). So you will need to refactor your code like

```
{  post.author.name === "Watson" ?
   Object.values(post.categories).map((category) => {
        return(
          <span>{category.name}</span>
        );
   : null
}
```

Note: You can still use `map` and `forEach` and have multiline code in them without issues. Thank you javascript for such convenience. Generally still advise to store the code as a function and execute it in the inline code.